# 3d Array to 2d Array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d, 2d

I have an array:
    [[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  12.]
      [ 0.  4.  0.  2.  11.]
      [ 0.  0.  2.  1.   0.]]
    [[ 0.  0.  2.  1.   0.]
     [ 0.  0.  2.  1.   0.]
     [ 0.  0.  2.  1.   0.]]]

I would like to collapse the above into:
    [[ 0.  0.  2.  1.  12.]
     [ 0.  4.  2.  3.  11.]
     [ 0.  0.  4.  2.   0.]
     ]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you give us more details: the code you have so far, what have you tried, and what problems have you run into?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can extract from the given example you want to merge the 3rd dimension by adding those components to a single number.

So the first column (on level 0)

```
 0 
 0
 0
 0
12
```

And the first column (on level 1)

```
0
0
2
1
0
```

Which will give

```
0
0
2
1
12
```

So for any value with coordinates (X,Y,Z) you want to project it to a field where the sum of the Z's stack at (X,Y)

```
(2,2,2) = 3
(2,2,1) = 4
(2,2,0) = 4
```

After projection:

```
(2,2) = 4+4+3 = 11
```

Hope this helps